# Filezilla not showing directory listing?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I had downloaded iptables from server to my windows desktop .I edited some lines for opening  port (2195) .after download i added some line for enabling port using this link

`http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/`

but it didn't enable that ports ....
so i revert back to old file (i undo all the changes) and uploaded that files.But this time when i try to access project directory through filezilla..It was no loading it.

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XX,XXX,XXX,XX,XXX)
Command:    MLSD
Error:      Connection timed out
Error:      Failed to retrieve directory listing`
```

Please suggest some solution.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turn on Active Mode rather than Passive and you should get it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issues viewing directory listing after you successfully logged in using FTP credentials then there is possibility that you have to connect to ftp server in Active mode rather than passive mode.

1. Add Ftp site to site manager
2. Click the Ftp site fill in the credentials and click transfer settings tab
3. Change transfer mode default to active.

It worked for me in the past , hope it works for you.

Comment: Ashx, still not its not listing any dierctory

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Funnily enough, it worked for me with Cyberduck, but that's not the case with FileZilla.